# Normal gitlab user with working keys cannot use PubkeyAuthentication to login to bash shell prompt

Tags: ssh, gitlab

On an Ubuntu server, 'foo.com', that serves gitlab, a gitlab user, 'bar', can clone, push, and pull without having to use a password, with no problem (public key is set up on the gitlab server for user 'bar').

User 'bar' wants to use the command line on the server 'foo', and does `ssh bar@foo.com`.  When user 'bar's ssh keys are not in 'foo''s `authorized_keys`, 'bar' is logged momentarily into Gitlab:

`debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, bar`

and then that session promptly exits.

When user 'bar's ssh key - even one that is not registered with GitLab - is in 'foo.com''s `authorized_keys`, then that user gets the expected result when doing `ssh bar@foo.com`.  However, then user `bar` (on their local computer) is unable to push, pull, clone, etc. from their gitlab-managed repository, with the error message being that "'some-group/some-project.git' does not appear to be a git repository".

It appears that there is a misconfiguration such that shell access is mixed up with gitlab project access.

How can user 'foo' be able to both login via ssh to a regular shell prompt and also use git normally (interacting with the remote git server from their local box)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching I got to know why this was happening on my end. I had the same issue. I wanted to use the same SSH key for both SSH login as well as GitLab access.

I found this thread helpful:
**https://gist.github.com/hanseartic/368a63933afb7c9f7e6b**

In the **[authorized_keys](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/authorized_keys/)** file, the gitlab-shell enters specific commands to limit the access. It adds the limitation once the user enters the public key through web interface. It uses the `command` option to do so.

We would need to modify the `command` option to allow access to `bash` and remember to remove the option of `no-pty` if listed in the comma-separated section. For example in my case I had this within the line: `no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty` *and had to remove no-pty from the list*.

A sample modified command should look like this:

```
command="if [ -t 0 ]; then bash; else /home/ec2-user/gitlab_service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-11; fi",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding ssh-rsa AAA...
```

*Need to be mindful to edit the correct command by checking the key number or the publickey and username associated with the command.*

This did not require any service restart.